# Unable to Find Space in Custom Function

Tags: php

As you can see in my next/previous link I have an extra space before the word "Previous" and I can't seem to find it.  Any help is greatly appreciated:

http://themeforward.com/demo2/?p=1813&page=2

Custom function:

```
// Custom Next/Previous Page
add_filter('wp_link_pages_args', 'wp_link_pages_args_prevnext_add');
/**
 * Add prev and next links to a numbered link list
 */
function wp_link_pages_args_prevnext_add($args)
{
    global $page, $numpages, $more, $pagenow;

    if (!$args['next_or_number'] == 'next_and_number') 
        return $args; # exit early

    $args['next_or_number'] = 'number'; # keep numbering for the main part
    if (!$more)
        return $args; # exit early

    if($page-1) # there is a previous page
        $args['before'] .= _wp_link_page($page-1)
            . $args['link_before']. $args['previouspagelink'] . $args['link_after'] . '</a>'
        ;

    if ($page<$numpages) # there is a next page
        $args['after'] = _wp_link_page($page+1)
            . $args['link_before'] . $args['nextpagelink'] . $args['link_after'] . '</a>'
            . $args['after']
        ;

    return $args;
}
```

Calling it:

```
<?php

wp_link_pages(array(
    'before' => '<p>' . __(''),
    'after' => '</p>',
    'next_or_number' => 'next_and_number', # activate parameter overloading
    'nextpagelink' => __('Next'),
    'previouspagelink' => __('Previous'),
    'pagelink' => '%',
    'echo' => 1 )
);

?>
```

Comment: not a WordPress related problem; a view into the html code in the browser clearly shows no extra space - and using a tool such as the Firefox 'web developer add-on' would quickly reveal css as the cause.

Comment: @Michael - it turns out WordPress was responsible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, well it turns out it has more to do with WordPress then we realised. The `wp_link_pages` function, in which the hook being used in the question resides, is the culprit rather than anything you've done. If you want to have a look, the function is in the post-template.php file inside the wp-includes directory.

The 'offending' code is in the loop that outputs the numbers (line 651 in WP3.3):

```
 for ( $i = 1; $i < ($numpages+1); $i = $i + 1 ) {
    $j = str_replace('%',$i,$pagelink);
    $output .= ' ';//This adds a space before the page number link
    if ( ($i != $page) || ((!$more) && ($page==1)) ) {
        $output .= _wp_link_page($i);
     }
     $output .= $link_before . $j . $link_after;
     if ( ($i != $page) || ((!$more) && ($page==1)) )
        $output .= '</a>';
  }
```

If you *really* wanted to get round it, (I don't recommend this) potentially you could return rather echo the html for the page list and then try to find the spaces using `preg_match` and remove them.

But really, there is *supposed* to be a space between the numbers and a so you might want to simply adapt the CSS so that it looks right (as mentioned above these elements have a margin around them).

Comment: That puts a space before the page _number_, as specified in the question, the problem is a space before the _Previous_ link. You can check out the source code of that page, there is no space before 'Previous' anywhere: `<p><a href="http://themeforward.com/demo2/?p=1813">Previous</a> <a href="http://themeforward.com/demo2/?p=1813">1</a> 2</p>
`. Using Google Chrome's developer tools I can uncheck the CSS rule I stated above, and it realigns the link to where he wants it.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I think I jumped to the assumption he was referring to a space after the 'Previous'.

Comment: No problem, looks like you get the vote after all! Lol :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a CSS rule `margin: 0 5px;` on `.tags a`, I think that is what's causing it to push it right ~1 space.

Also this is off-topic (not related to WordPress specifically).